VsCode "The System cannot find the file specified. 'Office, version=15.0.0.0' Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
few months ago I can debug my console application project that I created in VsCode however after few months it throws this error: I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library which I reference through Nuget Package Manager GUI



"unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
I've found a related post from this issue here somehow I'm confused with the solution. tried couple of things i.e Office Repair, use different version of excel interop but none have resolved the issue.

office.dll is the interop library that contains types that all Office apps use.  That nuget package for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is essentially broken, it should always include office.dll as well.  There used to be a nuget package for office.dll, but I don't see it anymore.  Just don't use these nuget packages, they are not reliable enough.  Instead use Project > Add COM Reference and select Excel.  Office.dll comes along for the ride.

@Hands Passant, thanks for your advise however I'm using VsCode . wonder how I can reference .dll in the csproject
